# In couchbase is it a good practice to store the cluster or bucket instance?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Is it okay to export bucket instance as given below?

module.exports.bucket = (new couchbase.Cluster(config.couchbase.server)).openBucket(config.couchbase.bucket);

Obviously I get the benefit of using the bucket object anywhere in my app. But will this have any performance impact?

Docs says

> A Couchbase SDK will also automatically adjust the port uses to
>   communicate to the Couchbase Server based on any changes to cluster
>   topology. Therefore it is not necessary to adjust your code for
>   connecting to accommodate cluster rebalance, or to accommodate node
>   addition or deletion.

Does that mean my code is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be good, bucket instances are expensive to initialize and thus should be reused (as confirmed in the [tuning section of the Node SDK doc](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/node-2.0/performance-tuning.html)).